# How do you find out a laptop screen panel manufacturer / model with Linux? (Samsung, LG, Chi Mei, etc)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop-display

How do you find out a laptop screen panel manufacturer / model with Linux?  (Samsung, LG, Chi Mei, etc)  + model number?

I've tried using this command  "lshw"  in Ubuntu, but it doesn't seem to have the panel listed in there.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use any utility that shows the EDID information.   One place to look for this information is in /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Comment: Thanks fpmurphy,  That log file did have a reference to the panel in there.   Interestingly, a Windows program called HWINFO64 seems to give a much more detailed description of the monitor "AU Optronics [model number], etc"    but the Linux Xorg.0.log file  has "AUO".   I wish I could find a similar program to HWINFO64 for Linux..   Still marking your answer as accepted since I can at least use it as a clue and it does indicate the brand.  Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

My info did not show up in XOrg.log. But I figured out that I could get the info from the DRM (Direct Rendering Manager) subcomponent of the linux kernel, which is exposed in sysfs. So I did the following:

```
root@dark:~# ls /sys/class/drm/
card0       card0-DP-2  card0-eDP-1     card0-HDMI-A-2  card0-VGA-1  version
card0-DP-1  card0-DP-3  card0-HDMI-A-1  card0-HDMI-A-3  controlD64
```

You can figure out which screens are active by doing some probing here:

```
root@dark:/sys/class/drm# cat card0-HDMI-A-2/enabled 
enabled
root@dark:/sys/class/drm# cat card0-HDMI-A-3/enabled 
disabled
```

I then parsed the EDID info from the screens I was interested in as follows:

```
root@dark:/sys/class/drm# cat card0-HDMI-A-1/edid | edid-decode
Extracted contents:
header:          00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00
serial number:   09 d1 0a 78 45 54 00 00 16 12
version:         01 03
basic params:    80 34 20 78 2e
chroma info:     c5 c4 a3 57 4a 9c 23 12 4f 52
established:     a5 6b 80
standard:        71 00 81 00 95 00 81 80 b3 00 a9 40 d1 00 01 01
descriptor 1:    28 3c 80 a0 70 b0 23 40 30 20 36 00 07 44 21 00 00 1a
descriptor 2:    00 00 00 ff 00 56 35 38 30 30 34 35 35 5a 4c 30 0a 20
descriptor 3:    00 00 00 fd 00 32 55 1f 5e 11 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20
descriptor 4:    00 00 00 fc 00 42 65 6e 51 20 47 32 34 30 30 57 0a 20
extensions:      01
checksum:        e5

Manufacturer: BNQ Model 780a Serial Number 21573
Made week 22 of 2008
EDID version: 1.3
Digital display
Maximum image size: 52 cm x 32 cm
Gamma: 2.20
DPMS levels: Off
Supported color formats: RGB 4:4:4, YCrCb 4:2:2
Default (sRGB) color space is primary color space
First detailed timing is preferred timing
Established timings supported:
  720x400@70Hz
  640x480@60Hz
  640x480@75Hz
  800x600@60Hz
  800x600@75Hz
  832x624@75Hz
  1024x768@60Hz
  1024x768@75Hz
  1280x1024@75Hz
  1152x870@75Hz
Standard timings supported:
  1152x720@60Hz
  1280x800@60Hz
  1440x900@60Hz
  1280x1024@60Hz
  1680x1050@60Hz
  1600x1200@60Hz
  1920x1200@60Hz
Detailed mode: Clock 154.000 MHz, 519 mm x 324 mm
               1920 1968 2000 2080 hborder 0
               1200 1203 1209 1235 vborder 0
               +hsync -vsync
Serial number: V5800455ZL0
 Monitor ranges: 50-85HZ vertical, 31-94kHz horizontal, max dotclock 170MHz
Monitor name: BenQ G2400W
 Has 1 extension blocks
Checksum: 0xe5

CEA extension block
Extension version: 3
22 bytes of CEA data
  Video data block
    VIC 04 
    VIC 16 (native)
    VIC 03 
    VIC 01 
    VIC 05 (native)
  Vendor-specific data block, OUI 000c03 (HDMI)
    Source physical address 1.0.0.0
  Speaker allocation data block
  Audio data block
Underscans PC formats by default
Basic audio support
Supports YCbCr 4:4:4
Supports YCbCr 4:2:2
1 native detailed modes
Detailed mode: Clock 74.250 MHz, 708 mm x 398 mm
               1280 1390 1430 1650 hborder 0
                720  725  730  750 vborder 0
               +hsync +vsync
Detailed mode: Clock 74.250 MHz, 708 mm x 398 mm
               1920 2008 2052 2200 hborder 0
                540  542  547  562 vborder 0
               +hsync +vsync interlaced
Detailed mode: Clock 27.000 MHz, 708 mm x 398 mm
                720  736  798  858 hborder 0
                480  489  495  525 vborder 0
               -hsync -vsync
Detailed mode: Clock 148.500 MHz, 708 mm x 398 mm
               1920 2008 2052 2200 hborder 0
               1080 1084 1089 1125 vborder 0
               +hsync +vsync analog composite
Detailed mode: Clock 25.180 MHz, 530 mm x 398 mm
                640  648  744  800 hborder 8
                480  482  484  525 vborder 8
               -hsync -vsync
Checksum: 0x2c
```

Great success!

Comment: I was disappointed to attempt this with a 3.18.12 kernel, and I can not locate any edid node inside /sys/class/drm/ .  I assume the kernel has changed too much since 2013.

Comment: @MutantBob: I'm only on 3.11, so I can't confirm your problem. But I still have the drm subdir, and some googling suggests it should still be present. Does your kernel have the DRM module loaded and do you have a graphics card driver which supports it? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7622/edid-information also suggests trying with 'xrandr --verbose', perhaps it can coax the information out?

Answer (score 4):

If you can install [read-edid](http://www.polypux.org/projects/read-edid/), then you can try with `get-edid | parse-edid`.

Answer (score 2):

Used `read-edid` to get this info on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
$ sudo apt-get install read-edid
$ sudo get-edid | parse-edid
This is read-edid version 3.0.1. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
3 potential busses found: 6 7 8
Will scan through until the first EDID is found.
Pass a bus number as an option to this program to go only for that one.
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 6
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "�
                     @"
    ModelName "�
                    @"
    VendorName "LGD"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 0 of 2014
    # EDID version 1.4
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 310 170
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 138.70 1920 1968 2000 2080 1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 1" 110.90 1920 1968 2000 2080 1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync 
EndSection
$
```

Poking around /sys/class/drm/card0 seemed to be an easy option.

```
cd /sys/class/drm/card0
$ for n in `find . -name edid` ; do cat $n | parse-edid 2>/dev/null; done
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "�
                     @"
    ModelName "�
                    @"
    VendorName "LGD"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 0 of 2014
    # EDID version 1.4
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 310 170
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 138.70 1920 1968 2000 2080 1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 1" 110.90 1920 1968 2000 2080 1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync 
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "VX2250 SERIES"
    ModelName "VX2250 SERIES"
    VendorName "VSC"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 40 of 2010
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Analog Display
    Option "SyncOnGreen" "true"
    DisplaySize 480 270
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 24-82
    VertRefresh 50-75
    # Maximum pixel clock is 210MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1600x1200, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1600x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1400x1050, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x800, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
EndSection
$
```

Answer (score 2):

This basically just wraps up Alexander Torstlings answer which worked for me. It is basically just a loop that gets info from all detected devices (and errors from the ones that cannot be probed). It just gives you the information quicker.

On my ubuntu 19.10 I first had to install the package edid-decode

```
sudo apt install edid-decode
```

Then the loop, which prints out the device name and info:

```
for i in $(ls /sys/class/drm/); do echo $i; cat /sys/class/drm/$i/edid | edid-decode; done
```

This should rather have been a comment on Alexander Torstlings answer than an independent one but as it seems, I am not allowed to comment yet... ;-)

Comment: Nice! Alas, `edid-decode` shows output when `edid` is empty. On systems with many potential outputs, this avoids that bogus output: `(cd /sys/class/drm/; for i in $(ls); do printf "\\n=== $i\\n\\n"; if [ ! -e "$i"/enabled ]; then echo "$i/enabled does not exist."; continue; fi; if [ ! "enabled" = "$(cat $i/enabled 2>&1)" ]; then echo "$i is not enabled"; continue; fi; if cat "$i"/edid | edid-decode |grep "No header found"; then :; else cat "$i"/edid | edid-decode; fi; done)|less`

Answer (score 1):

I found two tools on Linux Mint 18.1 that give different results. First I tried read-edid:

```
rich@laptop ~ $ sudo apt install read-edid
```

With that I got the following, but it didn't find the model number:

```
rich@laptop ~ $ sudo get-edid | parse-edid
    This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
    Attempting to use i2c interface
    No EDID on bus 0
    No EDID on bus 1
    No EDID on bus 3
    No EDID on bus 4
    No EDID on bus 5
    1 potential busses found: 2
    128-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 2
    Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
    Checksum Correct

    Section "Monitor"
        Identifier " 
                         @"
        ModelName " 
                        @"
        VendorName "LGD"
        # Monitor Manufactured week 0 of 2010
        # EDID version 1.3
        # Digital Display
        DisplaySize 380 220
        Gamma 2.20
        Option "DPMS" "false"
        Modeline    "Mode 0" 149.80 1920 1984 2080 2276 1080 1082 1085 1097 -hsync -vsync 
    EndSection
```

So then I tried another tool to parse the EDID:

```
rich@laptop ~ $ sudo apt install edid-decode
```

This seemed to give more information about the model of panel:

```
rich@laptop ~ $ sudo get-edid | edid-decode
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
1 potential busses found: 2
128-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 2
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Extracted contents:
header:          00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00
serial number:   30 e4 83 02 00 00 00 00 00 14
version:         01 03
basic params:    90 26 16 78 0a
chroma info:     f1 95 a3 55 52 a1 26 0f 50 54
established:     00 00 00
standard:        01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
descriptor 1:    84 3a 80 64 71 38 11 40 40 60 23 00 7f d7 10 00 00 19
descriptor 2:    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
descriptor 3:    00 00 00 fe 00 4c 47 20 44 69 73 70 6c 61 79 0a 20 20
descriptor 4:    00 00 00 fe 00 4c 50 31 37 33 57 46 31 2d 54 4c 42 32
extensions:      00
checksum:        ba

Manufacturer: LGD Model 283 Serial Number 0
Made week 0 of 2010
EDID version: 1.3
Digital display
Maximum image size: 38 cm x 22 cm
Gamma: 2.20
Supported color formats: RGB 4:4:4, YCrCb 4:2:2
First detailed timing is preferred timing
Established timings supported:
Standard timings supported:
Detailed mode: Clock 149.800 MHz, 383 mm x 215 mm
               1920 1984 2080 2276 hborder 0
               1080 1082 1085 1097 vborder 0
               -hsync -vsync 
Manufacturer-specified data, tag 0
ASCII string: LG
ASCII string: LP173WF1
Checksum: 0xba (valid)
EDID block does NOT conform to EDID 1.3!
    Digital display field contains garbage: 10
    Missing name descriptor
    Missing monitor ranges
    Detailed block string not properly terminated
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work better (all others answers didn't work 100% here):

```
for file in `ls -1 /sys/class/drm/*/edid`; do text=$(tr -d '\0' <"$file"); if [ -n "$text" ]; then edid-decode "$file" | grep -e Manufacturer: -e Product; sleep 0.0001; fi done
```

I tested here with 2 monitors. My primary is a builtin laptop monitor and the secondary is a DELL 25". This was the output:

```
Manufacturer: DELL Model 53359 Serial Number 809781068
Display Product Serial Number: YKFWP5790DGL
Display Product Name: DELL U2515H
Manufacturer: LGD Model 1133 Serial Number 0
```

To get **ONLY** the manufacturers/makers you can use this:

```
for file in `ls -1 /sys/class/drm/*/edid`; do text=$(tr -d '\0' <"$file"); if [ -n "$text" ]; then edid-decode "$file" | grep -e Manufacturer: | sed -n 's/Manufacturer: \(.*\) Model .*/\1/p'; sleep 0.0001; fi done
```

And you'll have this output:

```
DELL
LGD
```

You must have installed the `edid-decode` in your distro. My setup is DELL Latitude e5450 with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Why do you use the `sleep` command?

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora Core you can install `monitor-edid` (`read-edid` package seems to be available only for Ubuntu - I suggest adding Fedora info here since this forum is not `askubuntu`, but `superuser`).

It outputs `EISA ID`, with which you can find the vendor and device information on the internet.