# How to display LCD type in Embedded Linux such as Raspbian

Tags: linux, lcd, embedded-linux

I am interested in determining the hardware type of the LCD on a RetroGame that runs embedded linux. I would like to know if there is any command that can fetch a part number or anything that can help me determine the type of LCD panel that is being used. I just wanna know if the lCD that came is IPS version or not and its resolution.

I found something similar [here](https://superuser.com/questions/526497/how-do-you-find-out-a-laptop-screen-panel-manufacturer-model-with-linux-sams) but this is for regular desktop linux such as Ubuntu.

Running the following command:

> ls /sys/class/drm/

Results in

`bdi graphics mem misc 
i2c-adapter i2c-dev mmc-host sound 
tty usb_device vtconsole vc scsi_device 
scsi_generic scsi_host scsi_disk net rtc input`

Going into `graphics/fbo`  I get the following:

`bits_per_second modes name
stride blank name pan power 
cursor uevent virtual_size console`

Any help shall be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions in that other question you linked? Specifically, the one Alexander T. posted? That shouldn't be Ubuntu-specific as it's part of the Linux kernel.

Comment: yes, I tried `ls /sys/class/drm/` and `ls /var/log/` but the required info is not in those directories. The other option is to install software package `read-edid` which I cant install as the device has no wifi plus not sure if the device has required dependencies to even install additional packages. 
$

Comment: @SamForbis I updated my question